# Get the most recent file

Tags: java, file, nio

Using

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir,pattern);
```

I get a `DirectoryStream` of files in my `dir` which match `pattern`. But I'm not interested in all those files. I only want to get the most recent one and I know that the filename of the most recent one is the largest filename in terms of lexicographical order (because the timestamp is included). What is the easiest way to get this file? Is it always the one which comes last in my stream? What would you do?

Comment: Provided your files are in chronological order based on timestamp and assuming that newDirectoryStream orders them sensibly, then, yes, it would be the last entry in your stream.

Comment: I am assuming that the filename _starts with_ the timestamp. Is that right?

Comment: @ManoDestra My question is if newDirectoryStream does order them. If it orders them then I know by my file naming concept that it is the last file.

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is a code fragment that I believe is doing what you need.

```
        DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir,pattern);
        Path latestPath=null;
        FileTime latestTime = null;
        for (Path path:stream) {
            BasicFileAttributes attribs = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            FileTime time = attribs.creationTime();
            if (latestTime==null) {
                latestPath = path;
                latestTime = time;
            }
            else {
                if (time.compareTo(latestTime)>0) {
                    latestTime = time;
                    latestPath = path;
                }
            }
        }
```

Java 8 version :

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(null,"");
List<Path> list = new ArrayList()<>();
stream.forEach(list::add);
list.stream()
             .max((t,q)->{
                          BasicFileAttributes attribs1 = Files.readAttributes(t, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                          BasicFileAttributes attribs2 = Files.readAttributes(q, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                     return attribs1.creationTime().compareTo(attribs2.creationTime());});
```

I dont see any way we can stream straight from Iterator, so that is the best I can come up with when it comes to Java 8.

Comment: Thank you for solution. That's the standard way I would take if there was no better solution. I was wondering if there is a way (maybe using new Java 8 stream techniques) to get the path with muss less code in an elegant way. By the way: You don't need to compare the creation time, you simly may compare the filenames.

Comment: I am not sure it will be faster. Because what DirectoryStream implements is Iterator. We can only execute Consumer on iterator. In order to really stream it we need to convert it to collection. So Here is one quite ugly Java 8 version , but I dont thing anything better can come out of it.

Comment: Perhaps `stream.forEach(list::add)` defeats the purpose of using a _stream_; `DirectoryStream` could have been a proper Java 8 `Stream` :-(

Comment: In terms of performance yes. But in terms of readability no. But since the performance difference in the majority of the cases is negligible having a more conscious syntax has certain advantages I believe

Answer (score 1):

I am going to argue that since `DirectoryStream` does not really provide a Java 8 stream, falling back to the plain old `File` API may provide a more straightforward solution. For instance, the following program:

```
public class MostRecentFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path dir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        String regex = args[1];
        Arrays.stream(dir.toFile().listFiles(fn -> fn.getName().matches(regex))).sorted((f1, f2) -> {
                    try {
                        FileTime c2 = Files.readAttributes(f2.toPath(),
                           BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime();
                        FileTime c1 = Files.readAttributes(f1.toPath(),   
                           BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime();
                        return c2.compareTo(c1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            ).findFirst().ifPresent(f -> System.out.println("found: " + f.getName()));
    }
}
```

correctly prints the latest `.txt` file using first argument (say) `/tmp/files` and second argument `.*txt` (note: it is a regular expression, not a glob).

```
found: 6.txt
```

(The directory contains these files: `1      2      3.txt  5.txt  6.txt`).

Comment: May I know how do I execute this file when found?

Comment: That depends upon the operating system on which this code is running. One way is to let a properly configured "OS process" do it and watch the standard streams associated with that process. The Java abstraction that captures this is called `[ProcessExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start--). To my knowledge, there's no API like `File#execute` although there's an `File#canExecute` API that sets the _executable_ bit on the file permissions.